# How to cut a line in Xcode without selecting the text?

Tags: xcode, xcode11, xcode10

Many text editors and IDEs have this cool feature in which one can cut the entire line without having to select it previously. How can one do this on Xcode? Thanks.

Comment: Reopened: The marked duplicate is a bad answer with a hack that is no longer required.

Comment: @trojanfoe the duplicate is the question. One of the answers is exactly the same as yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keybinding is not set by default, but the command exists:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is there a way to activate it? Thanks

Comment: @haidarrr You will have to set your own key binding.

Comment: thanks for letting me know that. How do I do that though?

Comment: @haidarrr not sure - probably double click the setting and assign the keys. I’m sure there is help somewhere.

Comment: All I had to do was to double click and press enter and it let me. Thanks!!!